# how to insert random timestamp in snowflake timestamp field

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying the following SQL but I get an error:

```
CREATE TABLE slipstream( visit_timestamp time);
INSERT INTO slipstream values(dateadd(second, uniform(1, 10, random()), current_time()));
```

Error:

```
Invalid expression [DATE_ADDSECONDSTOTIME(CAST(UNIFORM(1, 10, RANDOM()) AS NUMBER(2,0)), '12:52:29.050000000')] in VALUES clause
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `INSERT - SELECT` pattern:

```
INSERT INTO slipstream (visit_timestamp)
SELECT dateadd(second, uniform(1, 10, random()), current_time());
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The VALUES requires constants and allows for simple casting that the SQL parser can do, thus in the values line you can have `'2022-06-21'::date` and that will correctly cast to DATE.

```
SELECT column1, system$typeof(column1) FROM VALUES 
    ('2022-06-21'::date),
    ('2022-05-21'::date);
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(COLUMN1) |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-21 | DATE[SB4] |
| 2022-05-21 | DATE[SB4] |

And thus for this workflow it would have been valid to use:

```
INSERT INTO slipstream VALUES 
    ('2022-06-21'::timestamp),
    ('2022-05-21'::timestamp);
```

| number of rows inserted |
| --- |
| 2 |

But complex function calls need to be executed SQL, thus as Lukasz mentioned the need for the INSERT/SELECT pattern.

Now you can be clever and put a VALUES on the SELECT to data drive the parameters to those functions (I was hoping to be clever as using the values to uniform, but those need to be constants, so settled for an offset)

```
CREATE TABLE slipstream( visit_timestamp time);

INSERT INTO slipstream 
SELECT dateadd(second, uniform(1, 10, random() ) + column1, current_time() )
    FROM VALUES
        (0),
        (-10), 
        (-20);
```

| number of rows inserted |
| --- |
| 3 |

```
SELECT * FROM slipstream;
```

| VISIT_TIMESTAMP |
| --- |
| 16:18:04 |
| 16:17:55 |
| 16:17:42 |